# Does a facemask with 4 corners require tzitzit?

Tags: tzitzis

I've come across facemasks that are 4 corned, therefore would it require tzitzit or as its for health reasons exclude this commandment.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A tallis requires two criteria which don't extend to face masks: that it be large enough to cover the majority of a child's body [SA OC 16](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.16.1) and that it actually be worn over one's body [SA OC 10:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.10.10). Since a face mask doesn't have either of these criteria, it cannot qualify as a Tallis.

Comment: thank you @DonielF

Comment: @Richard note this answer doesn't preclude potential Purim costumes for next year :)

Comment: now there is an idea! @DoubleAA

Comment: The Arukh haShulchan adds that it also has to be that the corners are around you. So, a jacket with 4 corners -- two at the top and two at the bottom of a front opening would still not require tzitzis either. (I am not saying this is specific to the AhS. But I am learning (and promoting) AhS Yomi -- http://www.aishdas.org/ahs-yomi . So that's the source I am remembering.)

Comment: @Micha In my experience many people are either unaware of that halacha or simply don't follow it in practice, considering how many people wear their talleisim. In any event, if an article of clothing doesn't cover one's body, the premise to "the four corners must surround the wearer" doesn't even start.